Menstruation leniencies on Shabbat
Is a menstruating woman exempt from any positive and negative aspects of Shabbat?

I'm not aware of anything in particular. Though pain medications that are prohibited for "a minor inconvenience" are permitted if someone feels "pain throughout their body, or enough that they have to lie down." So that certainly could qualify. Similarly, for a woman to pray at synagogue (vs. home) is a "plus", not a requirement; if she's not feeling up for it, that's a reasonable calculus.

Essentially -- there are some leniencies in general for people who are in pain or suffering (or potentially-embarrassing situations), and a woman during her period may, on a case-by-case basis, be included in those.


Shulchan Aruch OC 303:15

She [a woman] goes out [on Shabbat]…and with the wadding that she placed for her menstrual bleeding. Rema: So that blood not fall upon her and cause her discomfort. Shulchan Aruch: Even if it’s not tied, for since it is soiled, we are not concerned that perhaps she will carry it, even if it has a handle.
Two, she can use a cloth even just to protect herself from soiling,[42] so long as it’s so well attached that it can truly be considered a garment.
Shulchan Aruch OC 301:13
A woman in nidda who ties a cloth [only] in front of her that she not become dirty with her menstrual blood is prohibited from going out with it [on Shabbat] if it not be an apron-tied pant (sinar) fashioned in the way of clothing. But if she attaches it so that the blood will not cause her distress, it is permitted to go out with it.
The rough equivalent nowadays would be considering a tampon or a pad or even a menstrual cup, as functioning like clothing, and thus not an issue of carrying, as long as the purpose is to prevent discomfort. One could also argue that a pad attached firmly to a garment temporarily attains the halachic status of an article of clothing, and thus is permissible to keep in place even if only to prevent soiling or as a precaution in case a period will begin.[43]
Mekoros
